# Can't install Solaris 10 on XenServer 6.5 VM

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, xenserver, solaris-10

I have XenServer 6.5 installed on a server, and i have been trying to install Solaris 10 on a VM, it just get into the boot screen of the installation ISO, i proceed with ENTER and then this message appear:

```
WARNING: Attempting to load Xen drivers on non-Xen system
WARNING: Couldn't initialize xpv framework

panic [cpu0]/thread=fffffffffbc28340: unable to configure /xpvd nexus

fffffffffbc6ac70 hvm_bootstrap:hvmboot_rootconf +66 ()
fffffffffbc6acb0 unix: stubs_common_code+51 ()
fffffffffbc6ace0 genunix:roofconf +24 ()
fffffffffbc6ad10 genunix:vfs_mountroot +61 ()
fffffffffbc6ad50 genunix:main+117 ()
fffffffffbc6ad60 unix:_start+9d ()

skipping system dump - no dump device configured
rebooting...
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e33Aw.png)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix to this problem here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27300_01/E27307/html/vmrns-bugs.html#vmrns-solaris10hangs

7.3.21. Solaris 10 Release 8/11 Guest Hangs at Boot

When booting a virtual machine with Oracle Solaris 10 Release 8/11, the guest OS hangs when the copyright information screen appears. This is caused by a change in CPUID handling in dom0, which triggers a Solaris bug on platforms with CPUs of the Westmere-EP family.

Workaround: To make Solaris 10 run on Oracle VM 3.1.1, apply the following manual fix:

At boot, edit the grub menu: append the -kd kernel boot parameter. This runs the Solaris kernel debugger.

Continue the boot sequence up to Solaris kmdb.

At the kmdb prompt, enter the following command:

```
Welcome to kmdb
[0]> apix_enable/W 0
```

Enter :c to continue the system boot sequence.

When Solaris has been installed and has successfully booted, make this fix persistent by adding the following line to /etc/system:

```
set apix_enable = 0
```

Bug 13876544

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris 10 (or any version of Solaris for that matter) isn't a [supported guest](http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/38323-102-715588/XenServer-6.5.0_VM%20User's%20Guide.pdf) in  XenServer 6.5. Earlier versions appear to have supported it but not 6.x.

There is an interesting discussion on the [Citrix Discussins board](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/312251-solaris-10-installation-to-xenserver-602/) but the solutions appear to be erm experimental.

> What can I do?

Use a hypervisor that supports Solaris as a guest.